# TypeScript Mapped Types: Get element type of array

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

Suppose having a container type with array properties of unknown/generated types `T1`, `T2`, etc. (short `T*`):

```
interface MultiContainer
{
    Item1: T1[];
    Item2: T2[];
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to derive the following type using [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html%20mapped%20types):

```
interface SingleContainer
{
    Item1: T1;
    Item2: T2;
    ...
}
```

I'm looking for some expression like:

```
type SingleContainer =
    { [ P in keyof MultiContainer ]: MultiContainer[P] }
                                            └─────────── returns T*[] instead of T*
```

`MultiContainer[P]`returns the types `T*[]` but I need an expression that returns `T*`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this does what you need:

```
type SingleContainer = {[P in keyof MultiContainer]: MultiContainer[P][0]}
```

Answer (score 2):

From TS 2.8 it's possible to use `infer` keyword:

```
type SingleContainer = {
  [P in keyof MultiContainer]: MultiContainer[P] extends (infer T)[] ? T : never
};
```

Comment: Quite genius! This allows you to construct a `Flat<T>` type: `type Flat<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends (infer A)[] ? A : T[P]; }`.
Usage: `interface MixedContainer { Item1: T1; Item2: T2[] }; type FlatContainer = Flat<MixedContainer>; // { Item1: T1; Item2: T2 }`
Throw in some string template typing and you can even go from `{ Items: T1[] }` to `{ Item: T1 }`.