# Typescript complex mapped types that extract generic

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

Similar to [TypeScript Mapped Types: Get element type of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44848274/typescript-mapped-types-get-element-type-of-array), I have a type, say:

```
type A = {
   Item1: Promise<string>,
   Item2: Promise<number>,
   Item3: number
}
```

I'd like to extract the following type from it:

```
type A' = {
   Item1: string,
   Item2: number,
   Item3: number
}
```

Note the added complexity of one of the fields NOT being a Promise.

Is this even possible or am I just reaching the limits of typescripts abilities to infer types? I tried fiddling around with mapped types and Record types but I just couldn't figure it out.

**UPDATE:**

Say I want to do the same with function calls instead:

```
type A = {
  Item1: (string, number) => Promise<string>,
  Item2: () => Promise<number>,
  Item3: () => number
}
```

And the desired type is:

```
type A' = {
  Item1: (string, number) => string,
  Item2: () => number,
  Item3: () => number
}
```

I thought this would be similar enough to the first case I state but function return values don't seem as straight forward as I would have hoped.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### UPDATE 2020-01-28

Since TypeScript 2.8 introduced [conditional types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) you can now do this mapping with relative ease:

```
type A = {
  Item1: (x: string, y: number) => Promise<string>,
  Item2: () => Promise<number>,
  Item3: () => number,
  Item4: Promise<string>,
  Item5: Promise<number>,
  Item6: number
}

type UnpromiseObj<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Promise<infer U> ? U :
  T[K] extends (...args: infer A) => Promise<infer R> ? (...args: A) => R :
  T[K]
}

type Aprime = UnpromiseObj<A>;
/* type Aprime = {
  Item1: (x: string, y: number) => string;
  Item2: () => number;
  Item3: () => number;
  Item4: string;
  Item5: number;
  Item6: number;
} */
```

I'll leave the below so that the crazy nonsense you had to go through before conditional types existed can be preserved for posterity:

### END UPDATE 2020-01-28

---

It's not exactly *impossible*, but without official support for [mapped conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12424) or [the like](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6606), it's iffy. Let's try.  First, let's set up some type-level boolean logic:

```
type False = '0';
type True = '1';
type Bool = False | True;
type If<Cond extends Bool, Then, Else> = { '0': Else; '1': Then }[Cond];
```

So the type `If<True, Then, Else>` evaluates to `Then`, and the type `If<False, Then, Else>` evaluates to `Else`.

The first issue is that you need to be able to determine if a type is a `Promise` or not.  The second is that you need to be able to get at the type of `T`, given a `Promise<T>`.  I will do this by augmenting the declarations for the `Object` and `Promise<T>` interfaces with some phantom properties which won't exist at runtime:

```
// if you are in a module you need to surround 
// the following section with "declare global {}"
interface Object {
  "**IsPromise**": False
}
interface Promise<T> {
  "**IsPromise**": True
  "**PromiseType**": T
}
```

That was the iffy part.  It's not great to augment global interfaces, since they are in everyone's namespace.  But it has the desired behavior: any `Object` which is not a `Promise` has a `False` type for its `"**IsPromise**"` property, and a `Promise` has a `True` value.  Additionally, a `Promise<T>` has a `"**PromiseType**"` property of type `T`.  Again, these properties don't exist at runtime, they're just there to help the compiler.

Now we can define `Unpromise` which maps a `Promise<T>` to `T` and leaves any other type alone:

```
type Unpromise<T extends any> = If<T['**IsPromise**'], T['**PromiseType**'], T>
```

And `MapUnpromise` which maps `Unpromise` onto an object's properties:

```
type MapUnpromise<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Unpromise<T[K]>
}
```

Let's see if it works:

```
type A = {
   Item1: Promise<string>,
   Item2: Promise<number>,
   Item3: number
}
    
type Aprime = MapUnpromise<A>
// evaluates to { Item1: string; Item2: number; Item3: number; }
```

Success!  But we've done some fairly unpleasant things to types to get it to happen, and it might not be worth it.  That's up to you!

Hope that helps; good luck!

---

#### Update 1

Doing the same with function calls is unfortunately not possible, as far as I can tell.  You'd really need something like an [extended `typeof` type query](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6606) and that just isn't part of TypeScript for now (as of TypeScript v2.5 anyway).

So you can't take your type `A` and compute `APrime` from it (note that `A'` isn't a valid identifier.  Use `Aʹ` if you want).  But you can make a base type from which you can compute both `A` and `APrime`:

```
type False = '0';
type True = '1';
type Bool = False | True;
type If<Cond extends Bool, Then, Else> = { '0': Else; '1': Then }[Cond];
type MaybePromise<Cond extends Bool, T> = If<Cond, Promise<T>, T>
```

I've given up on global augmentation and added `MaybePromise<Cond, T>`, where `MaybePromise<True, T>` evaluates to `Promise<T>`, and `MaybePromise<False, T>` evaluates to `T`.  Now we can get `A` and `APrime` using `MaybePromise<>`:

```
type ABase<Cond extends Bool> = {
  Item1: (s: string, n: number) => MaybePromise<Cond, string>,
  Item2: () => MaybePromise<Cond, number>,
  Item3: () => number
}

type A = ABase<True>;
// evaluates to { 
//   Item1: (s: string, n: number) => Promise<string>; 
//   Item2: () => Promise<number>; 
//   Item3: () => number; }


type APrime = ABase<False>;
// evaluates to { 
//   Item1: (s: string, n: number) => string; 
//   Item2: () => number; 
//   Item3: () => number; }
```

So this works!  But the refactoring I suggest might not play nicely with your use case.  It depends on how you acquire the `A` type in the first place.  Oh well, that's the best I can do.  Hope it's of some help.  Good luck again!

Comment: This is great! I've never really looked at writing logic with types before. Is there anywhere specific I can learn more about this kind of logic? I'd like to be able to recognize these kinds of issues. Also, is there a reason why `type False` is not just `= false` instead of the string value `0`?

Comment: Ah, I see. Can't use booleans as keys into an object for the `If` type

Comment: So turns out my toy case didn't exactly fit my real case scenario, I forgot that the promises were actually wrapped in a function. I've updated the question.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't give you any great handle to take a function type and get its return type.  I could suggest a refactoring that is simpler but might not be how you want to go.  I'll think about it and update the answer.

Comment: If you're interested in the idea of encoding logic and other ideas into your type system, look up "type-level programming".  Languages like [Scala](http://gigiigig.github.io/tlp-step-by-step/introduction.html) and [Haskell](http://www.parsonsmatt.org/2017/04/26/basic_type_level_programming_in_haskell.html) make use of this.  TypeScript is so new that I don't see a lot of resources for type-level programming in it.

Comment: Once again, thank so much for your detailed answer. I actually should be able to use something like this, because I control where the inputs are being created.

Answer (score 1):

It has gotten easier nowadays with TypeScript 4.5's `Awaited` utility type:

```
type A = {
  Item1: Promise<string>;
  Item2: Promise<number>;
  Item3: number;
  Item4: (arg0: string, arg1: number) => Promise<string>;
  Item5: () => Promise<number>;
  Item6: () => number;
};

type AwaitValues<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: infer P) => infer R
    ? (...args: P) => Awaited<R>
    : Awaited<T[K]>;
};

type A2 = AwaitValues<A>;
```

And by hovering `A2` we can see its type to be:

```
/*
type A2 = {
    Item1: string;
    Item2: number;
    Item3: number;
    Item4: (arg0: string, arg1: number) => string;
    Item5: () => number;
    Item6: () => number;
}
*/
```

Comment: You can do this even more succinctly by inferring the parameters and return type! https://tsplay.dev/NrKjzm

Comment: Nice! Let me edit that in.